# jQuery unobtrusive Validation don't working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I have form in mvc 4 that don't make validation on client side.

The validation happen only only on the server side.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

the bundle code is:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

I also checked the web.config settings:

```
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

The model I using is:

```
public class ContactUs
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

The page is inside the _Layout file.
Scripts version:
jquery 2.0.3s and
jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1

All the scripts is working and exist on the source code of the page.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Show us your model too? Have you put annotations on your model properties?

Comment: Thanks for your response. the model with the annotations added to the question

Comment: You have jquery.unobtrusive and jquery.validate, do you have the base jquery library included?

Comment: Yes. It's in the _Layout file and I tested it's exist on the loaded page

Comment: What if you move the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` to your _Layout file and before the `@RenderBody()` call?

Comment: I put it before the @RenderBody() and after and it still don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added link to the CDN script http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
and now it's working.

After looking on my project history I found that for some reason when I updated my NuGet packages it removed this script from my project and then my client side validations stop working.

I tried to add this script with NuGet packages like "Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation" or "Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax" and some more packages like this and it didn't fix the problem so I added the CDN script and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to tell the validation summary not to exclude property errors:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're actually getting an error?  Might want to debug and check in the controller action that the `ModelState` is invalid and contains the errors you are expecting.

Comment: I getting the validation error after the server side return from submitting the form. But not on the client side. The goal I want to accomplish is that it won't get to the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today and i've put 3 files on bundle/jqueryval:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"));
```